# Use terraform to create multiple listeners with same configurations for multiple load balancer ARN's

Tags: amazon-web-services, listener, amazon-elb

I have a `resource "aws_lb_listener"` with a `default_action` that needs to be added for multiple Load balancers. The way I see is creating individual resources with `load_balancer_arn` for all the load balancers.

Since the default action is common, Is there a way to create listener for each AWS LB

```
resource "aws_lb" "front_end" {
  # ...
}

resource "aws_lb" "front_end_2" {
  # ...
}


resource "aws_lb" "front_end_3" {
  # ...
}

resource "aws_lb_listener" "front_end" {
  load_balancer_arn = ["${aws_lb.front_end.arn}", "${aws_lb.front_end_2.arn}", "${aws_lb.front_end_3.arn}"] // I know this is incorrect but something like this (for each LB, create listener with following config)
  port              = "443"
  protocol          = "HTTPS"

  default_action {
    ....
    }
  }
}
```

In the above example, the listener configuration for all the three Load balancers is same. Hence wanting to create listener for each load balancer.

Comment: What is your current TF code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you want to keep your `aws_lb` as 3 independent resources, then you can use [for_each](https://www.terraform.io/language/meta-arguments/for_each#the-for_each-meta-argument) to create 3 listeners for them.

```
resource "aws_lb_listener" "front_end" {

  for_each = toset([aws_lb.front_end.arn, aws_lb.front_end_2.arn, aws_lb.front_end_3.arn])

  load_balancer_arn = each.value
  port              = "443"
  protocol          = "HTTPS"

  default_action {
    ....
    }
  }
}
```